# How to remove sep. rule from blank pages when using two-column mode?

Tags: two-column, rules, blank-page

In the following example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
  \twocoltocetc
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{test}

  \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

I get a vertical line one the blank pages, which looks ugly. How can I force to only have the vertical column line where there's content?

Comment: memoir doesn't have its own code for this, so it is `\@outputdblcol` in `latex.ltx` (or `fixltx2e`) that does it.

I think it's too late to determine whether any of the halves are empty there though, so I think a solution has to store somewhere that a page was empty, and then `@outputdblcol` should look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enclose a patch to your problem by redefining the `\newpage` command and a preview of twelve pages.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{6pt}
\begin{document}
\let\oldcdp=\newpage
\def\newpage{%
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
  \oldcdp
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{6pt}}
  \twocoltocetc
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{test}
  \lipsum[1-28]
  \chapter{test}
  \lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Unfortunately, it only redraws the vertical line on the last page immediately before the `\clearpage`. I'm working on modifying the `\chapter` command to enable drawing again to work around this.

Comment: Ha! Got it! Memoir has a hook that I could use: `\renewcommand{\memendofchapterhook}{\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}}`

Comment: That's perfect! See my edit, I have hooked the `\newpage` command...

Comment: Even better! Hm, for some reason, in my document the _last_ page doesn't get the vertical line... Oh well, I'll use the slightly more verbose version for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An empty page is usually created by `\cleardoublepage`, which is used by the document division commands (`\chapter`, ...). In case of class `memoir` there is also `\cleartorecto` and `\cleartoverso`. The following example (based on Malipivo's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170540/16967)) patches these commands to reset the column rule width to zero.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5\columnsep}% larger rule for illustration

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\patchclearpage}[1]{%
  \patchcmd{#1}{%
    \thispagestyle{cleared}%
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn
      \hbox{}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  }{%
    \thispagestyle{cleared}%
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn
      \begingroup
        \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}%
        \hbox{}%
        \newpage
      \endgroup
    \fi
  }{%
  }{%
    \errmessage{Patching of \string#1 failed}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\patchclearpage\cleartorecto
\patchclearpage\cleartoverso
\patchclearpage\cleardoublepage

\begin{document}
  \twocoltocetc
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{test}
  \lipsum[1-14]
  \newpage\null\newpage
  \lipsum[15-28]
  \chapter{test}
  \lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]